# Trusty is not installing programs/icons such as Dropbox on the top panel bar. Anyone know a fix?

Tags: 14.04

This is not only a dropbox issue it's for other programs that also want to reside in the top bar.  Anyone know how to resolve

Answer (score 1):

For Dropbox type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1` did work.